# InvalidOperationException When connecting to mySQL database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm currently using .NET Framework 4.8 and I can't seem to get into my database. The password and other connection info has been tested elsewhere and is valid, so does anyone know why I continue to get this exception?
`System.InvalidOperationException:'Internal connection fatal error.'`
When I run the following simple code?

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("...");

conn.Open();
conn.Close();
```

I'm just trying to get into the database, not even query yet...
Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Use `MySqlConnection` and remove `,3306` from your connection string; that's not valid syntax. It should be `Server=rdsmysql01.cydxztqqjsyj.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;`.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger while  I'm sure you're right, this doesn't fix the issue. I still need a way to specify the port...

Comment: 3306 is the default port, so you don't need to specify it. But if you want/need to: `Server=rdsmysql01.cydxztqqjsyj.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;Port=3306;`. See https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Data.SqlClient` is the SQL Server driver.  You need the MySql driver, which is [available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/).